# 2011 Kia Optima Repair

Tags: engine, starting, kia, optima

While driving my 2011 Kia Optima LX with 58,000 miles, the engine shut off and I coasted to a stop.  Attempting to restart resulted in one weak crank then nothing.  There is fuel and electricity.  The engine warning light came on right as it shut down.  I have 2,000 miles left on my bumper-to-bumper warranty.  Any ideas?

Comment: My idea? Have Kia tow it to their shop and have them fix it under warranty. You have 2k on the B2B, but there is still another 40k left on the powertrain, which this should probably fall under. You could check the battery, though. While I've not seen an engine die because of a weak battery (first time for everything), your description of it not wanting to crank is pointing that way. This should also be covered under the B2B warranty, if my recollection serves me.